# first drop down button value selected then according to the value selected the second drop down list should come flutter.the problem is as th

Tags: flutter, dropdown, flutter-dropdownbutton

In a stateful widget 2 drop down buttons are called at the same time

```
class Idnum extends StatefulWidget {
  String courseselectedValue;
  String sectionselectedvalue;
  Idnum(
      {Key? key,
      required this.courseselectedValue,
      required this.sectionselectedvalue})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Idnum> createState() => _IdnumState();
}

class _IdnumState extends State<Idnum> {
  late Future<dynamic> searchstd;

  late Future<Searchstdsectionmodel?> sections;
  List<SearchStudentsModel> coursesitems = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    searchstd = searchstdinfojson();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton.icon(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: commoncolor,
          elevation: 3,
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
          minimumSize: const Size(170, 38),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Dialog(
                          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                idtitle("Search Student"),
                                sizedh10,
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    idtitle("Course"),
                                    const Text(
                                      "*",
                                      style:
                                          TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrange),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                coursesdropdown(widget.courseselectedValue),
                                sizedh5,
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    idtitle("Section"),
                                    const Text(
                                      "*",
                                      style:
                                          TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrange),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                sectiondropdown(widget.sectionselectedvalue),
                                sizedh5,
                                idtitle("Student Name"),
                                sizedh5,
                                idtextfield("Enter ID number"),
                                sizedh15,
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    ElevatedButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          
                                        },
                                        child: const Text("Submit"),
                                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                          primary: commoncolor,
                                          elevation: 3,
                                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                                          minimumSize: const Size(80, 32),
                                        )),
                                    sizedw10,
                                    ElevatedButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          Navigator.pop(context);
                                        },
                                        child: const Text("Cancel"),
                                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                          primary: orancolor,
                                          elevation: 3,
                                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                                          minimumSize: const Size(80, 32),
                                        ))
                                  ],
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
              });
        },
        icon: const Icon(Icons.person_pin_outlined),
        label: const Text(
          "Search Student",
        ));
  }
```

this is the ui
and in this the coursedropdown button when selected the value it saves an id of the particular value selected and it passes to the api of the second dropdown button's

```
FutureBuilder<dynamic> coursesdropdown(String courseselectedValue) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: searchstdinfojson(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            SearchStudentsModel list = snapshot.data;
            print("$list");
            List<dynamic> courseitems = [];

            Map<String, String> snk = {};

            for (int i = 0; i < list.data!.courses!.length; i++) {
              print("COURSE ID ${list.data!.courses![i]}");
              courseitems.add(list.data!.courses![i].courseName);

              snk["${list.data!.courses![i].courseName}"] =
                  "${list.data!.courses![i].id}";
            }
            return DropdownButtonFormField2(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  isDense: true,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  border: InputBorder.none),
              isExpanded: true,
              hint: const Text(
                'Select ',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Color(0xFFB3B1B1)),
              ),
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                color: Colors.black45,
              ),
              iconSize: 30,
              dropdownMaxHeight: 100,
              scrollbarAlwaysShow: true,
              buttonHeight: 35,
              buttonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                border: Border.all(width: 0, color: Colors.transparent),
                color: Colors.grey[300],
              ),
              buttonPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 10),
              dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              ),
              items: courseitems
                  .map((value) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: "$value",
                        onTap: () {
                          print("this is selected vaue ${value}");
                          print("this is  ${snk}");
                          print("this is the class id ${snk[value]}");
                          Savetoken.savecourseid("${snk[value]}");
                          print(Savetoken.savecourseid("${snk[value]}"));
                          Savetoken.getcourseId();
                          print("this is get ${Savetoken.getcourseId()}");
                          sectiondropdown("");
                          
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          "$value",
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ))
                  .toList(),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null) {
                  return 'Please select .';
                }
                return null;
              },
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  sectiondropdown("");
                });
              },
              onSaved: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  courseselectedValue = value.toString();
                });
              },
            );
          }
          return Container();
        });
  }
```

this is the code of the coursedropdownbutton's

```
FutureBuilder<dynamic> sectiondropdown(String sectionselectedvalue) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: searchstdsectionjson(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          print("this is almost correct");
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print("this is correct");
            Searchstdsectionmodel list = snapshot.data;

            List<dynamic> sectionitems = [];

            Map<String, String> snks = {};

            for (int i = 0; i < list.data!.sections!.length; i++) {
              sectionitems.add(list.data!.sections![i].sectionName);

              snks["${list.data!.sections![i].sectionName}"] =
                  "${list.data!.sections![i].id}";
            }
            return DropdownButtonFormField2(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  isDense: true,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  border: InputBorder.none),
              isExpanded: true,
              hint: const Text(
                'Select ',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Color(0xFFB3B1B1)),
              ),
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                color: Colors.black45,
              ),
              iconSize: 30,
              dropdownMaxHeight: 100,
              scrollbarAlwaysShow: true,
              buttonHeight: 35,
              buttonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                border: Border.all(width: 0, color: Colors.transparent),
                color: Colors.grey[300],
              ),
              buttonPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 10),
              dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              ),
              items: sectionitems
                  .map((value) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: "$value",
                        onTap: () {
                          print("this is selected vaue ${value}");
                          print("this is  ${snks}");
                          print("this is the class id ${snks[value]}");
                          Savetoken.savesectionid("${snks[value]}");
                          print(Savetoken.savesectionid("${snks[value]}"));
                          Savetoken.getsectionId();
                          print("this is get ${Savetoken.getsectionId()}");
                          return;
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          "$value",
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ))
                  .toList(),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null) {
                  return 'Please select .';
                }
                return null;
              },
              onChanged: (value) {},
              onSaved: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  sectionselectedvalue = value.toString();
                });
              },
            );
          }
          print("this is");
          return nullsectiondropdown();
        });
  }

  Widget nullsectiondropdown() {
    final List<String> sam = [];
    return DropdownButtonFormField2(
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
          isDense: true,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          border: InputBorder.none),
      isExpanded: true,
      hint: const Text(
        'no data ',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Color(0xFFB3B1B1)),
      ),
      icon: const Icon(
        Icons.arrow_drop_down,
        color: Colors.black45,
      ),
      iconSize: 30,
      buttonHeight: 35,
      buttonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        border: Border.all(width: 0, color: Colors.transparent),
        color: Colors.grey[300],
      ),
      buttonPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 10),
      dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      ),
      items: sam
          .map((countryone) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: countryone,
                onTap: () {
                  Savetoken.getcourseId();
                },
                child: Text(
                  countryone,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                  ),
                ),
              ))
          .toList(),
      validator: (value) {
        return null;
      },
      onChanged: (value) {},
      onSaved: (value) {},
    );
  }
```

this is the code of the section drop down button's
the problem is as the code gets called at the same time the api of the sectiondropdown button wont work and then it automatically goes to the code which is written when there is no data

Comment: While the snippet depends on future and api is not available to test. You can follow some steps. 1st get the data and create Map key will be used for 1st dropdown and values will be for second dropdown. Must use nullable dropdown value especially for second one. Another most important part is set to second dropdown while you change the 1st dropdown value.

Comment: make second dropdown disabled and set value to empty. after first dropdown filled/changed, get data from api. then set data to second dropdown and enabled second dropdown. call setstate to change ui.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).